# How to install Jupyter Notebook on a linux server with no internet access?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have one Windows server with internet access and one Linux server with no internet access, and I can transfer any files from Windows server to Linux server. The Linux server already has python installed. How can I install Jupyter Notebook on the Linux server?

Comment: mamba, conda, or pip? For pip, you can use the one with internet to download packages (`pip download`) with all dependencies as wheels to given folder, then move it and install there. That's what I did in my vanilla python environment. I assume others should have something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download notebook-master.zip file from https://github.com/jupyter/notebook and unzip it.
2. Connect to the Linux Server using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).
3. Transfer the notebook master folder to the Linux machine
4. On the Linux machine, go to the directory and run `pip install .`. Alternatively, If you do not have pip installed you can run `python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/`

Comment: Thanks, pip install does not work, when I run `python3 setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/`, it reports `npm unavailable
Failed to run bower: [Errno 2] No such file or directory...`. Do you know how to solve such an issue?

Comment: can you try using pip3?